# Install DLL Server on x64 Windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, dll, installation

I need to install a shell extension (64-bit DLL server) for the contextual menu on any version of Windows x64. I'm able to register the extension just fine (regsvr32) if on the target system I have installed the redistributable files for VS 9.0 SP1 x64 (setup file from Microsoft).

However I have to make a setup and cannot require the user to have those files already installed so I need to include the redistributable CRT and MFC DLLs in my setup in the same folder as my DLL.

I've tried to include the 64 bit redistributable DLLs from my VS 9.0 SP1 (called AMD64) but they don't seem to work. What am I doing wrong? What DLLs should I use?

Comment: Which path are you running regsvr32 from?
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/282747

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, my DLL is 64-bit. Regsvr32 works fine when I have the x64 dlls installed. The problem is what dlls should I include in my setup so there is no need to install the Microsoft redist dlls for VS 9.0 SP1?

Comment: @Cosmin: Why not just statically link the runtime?

Comment: @Billy ONeal: I expect to use those DLLs also for an executable in the same program.

Comment: @Cosmin: It's still not worth it IMHO. So you waste a few hundred k by linking it statically, and save you and your customers hours of headaches if/when DLLs don't match up somewhere along the line, because you tried to do unsupported things (namely, copying the CRT dll instead of installing it).

Comment: Agreed, using a shell extension handler in another program is a very long shot anyway.  I'd guess the mistake is trying to deploy the Debug build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by statically linking the required libraries. The size is much smaller than having the executable + dlls. I can do that for my shell extension but not for the main application since there are conflicts with the included libraries.

Thanks Billy ONeal for the suggestion, I was ignoring the obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into Microsoft Merge Modules.  Since you haven't listed what technology you are making your setup with I can't give any more specific guidance than that however.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235290%28VS.80%29.aspx